# How to find all instances of mirrored duplicates?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have been searching for some time now for any answers on how to do this.

What I am trying to do is, take an array of numbers, e.g. `{1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 6 ,5, 3, 1}` (but it will use user input) and find the duplicates of these numbers that are mirrored and return how many indexes are involved in just one instance of said array.

I know the basics of C# but can't grasp this task. No, this is not homework. This is my own project to further my knowledge.

I am not currently around the code I have for parts of this, but would really appreciate any help/advice anyone could give me.

Comment: Please could you give the expected result, I am still not clear

Comment: Definition/explanation/sample of "mirrored duplicates" would give this question a chance...

Comment: Do you expect to return `1, 3, 5, 6`? I.e. the same integer in the same index when reversed?

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] array =  {1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 6 ,5, 3, 1};

//holds left index of mirrored pair, you can easily find the right one
var mirroredIndexes = new List<int>();
var length = array.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
{
    if(array[i] == array[length - i - 1])
        mirroredIndexes.Add(i);
}

mirroredIndexes.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
Console.WriteLine ("total of {0} mirrored pairs ({1})", 
                       mirroredIndexes.Count, 
                       string.Join(", ", mirroredIndexes.Select(i => array[i])));
```

prints next indexes:

```
0
1
2
3
total of 4 mirrored pairs (1, 3, 5, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after. This will return a list of matching indices. 
Eg. first == last, second == second to last, third == third to last

```
var matches = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

var array = new [] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0 };

if (array.Length % 2 != 0)
    throw new Exception("Array must have an even amount of elements");

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length / 2; i++)
{
    if (array[i] == array[array.Length - 1 - i])
    {
        matches.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(i, array.Length - 1 - i));
    }
}

var firstMatchingIndex1 = matches[0].Item1;
// This will be 0

var firstMatchingIndex2 = matches[0].Item2;
// This will be 9
```

You could go further, using a custom class, and capture the actual value that matched (eg. index1 is 1, index2 is 8 and the value was 1.